# Python 2.7 + Scapy 2.3.1

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to using `scapy` but I don't know why some functions don't work:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import *
a = Ether() / IP(dst='192.168.1.1') / ICMP()
a.show()
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    a.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 819, in show
###[ Ethernet ]###
    reprval = f.i2repr(self,fvalue)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 191, in i2repr
    x = self.i2h(pkt, x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 88, in i2h
    x = conf.neighbor.resolve(pkt,pkt.payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 38, in resolve
    return self.resolvers[k](l2inst,l3inst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 727, in <lambda>
    conf.neighbor.register_l3(Ether, IP, lambda l2,l3: getmacbyip(l3.dst))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 56, in getmacbyip
    iff,a,gw = conf.route.route(ip)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'
```

Without `.show()` it works and :

```
pck = Ether()
pck.show()
```

works too.

I tried some other functions like `.show`, but sometimes I get this error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import everything, so try changing your import statement as shown below:

```
$ sudo python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scapy.all import *
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>>> a = Ether() / IP(dst='192.168.1.1') / ICMP()
>>> a.show()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = 74:11:d5:04:1b:82
  src       = 80:f6:df:59:3d:35
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4
     ihl       = None
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = None
     id        = 1
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = icmp
     chksum    = None
     src       = 192.168.0.5
     dst       = 192.168.1.1
     \options   \
###[ ICMP ]###
        type      = echo-request
        code      = 0
        chksum    = None
        id        = 0x0
        seq       = 0x0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a step, your first line specifies how to construct a/some packets, show tries to dissect received packet(s).

Try something like:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import *
a = Ether() / IP(dst='192.168.1.1') / ICMP() # Rule for creating packets
s,r = sr1(a) # Send & Receive one packet(s)
r.show() # Show the recieved packet(s)
```

This uses your rule to construct a single packet, send it and capture the reply/replies, then shows the actual packet.

Comment: It makes Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/inck/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    s,r = sr1(a) # Send & Receive one packet(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 334, in sr1
    s=conf.L3socket(filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, iface=iface)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 307, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
[...]
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: You need superuser (root) permission because it creates a socket. Just sudo and you are set to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is scapy trying to be smart about filling in valid defaults in the link layer. It doesn't handle things gracefully when you don't import the entire module.

If you change your code just a little bit so that it doesn't need to do that check it will build your packet.

```
from scapy.layers.inet import *
a = Ether(src='AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA', dst='BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB') / IP(src='192.168.1.1') / ICMP()
a.show()
```